# Multiple struct variable get assigned same values unintentionally

Tags: c, struct

My program has a `struct` that contains 2 variables and 3 function pointers as follows in the file `demo.h`:

```
#ifndef DEMO_H
#define DEMO_H



typedef struct {

    int structNumber;
    char *name;

    void (* setName)(char *);

     int (* getStructNumber)();
     char *(* getName)();
} *structure;



structure newStructure(); // This function builds an object kind of, of the structure and returns a pointer to it.


#endif
```

And the implementation of these functions here in `demo.c`:

```
#include "demo.h"
#include <stdlib.h>



structure obj; // Theres definitely something wrong with the usage of this variable in function newStructure().



void setName(char *name) {

    obj->name = name;
}



char *getName() {

    return obj->name;
}


int getStructNumber() {

    return obj->structNumber;
}



structure newStructure() {

    static int structNumber = 0;
    structNumber ++;

    structure ob = (structure)malloc(sizeof(*ob));

    // Actually I've used this obj variable
    // so that this ob is accessible in other functions too.
    // But I suppose I am not using it properly.
    // I don't wish to pass ob as a parameter to other functions.
    // The program works fine if I pass it as parameters. 
    // But I want to do it without passing it as parameters.
    obj = ob;

    ob->structNumber = structNumber;


    // Assigning the function pointers.
    ob->setName = setName;
    ob->getStructNumber = getStructNumber;
    ob->getName = getName;


    return ob;
}
```

And this is the `main` function in the file `main.c`:

```
#include "demo.h"
#include <stdio.h>



int main() {

    void displayData(structure);

    structure str1 = newStructure();
    structure str2 = newStructure();
    structure str3 = newStructure();

    str1->setName("Robin Hood");
    str2->setName("Tiger Woods");
    str3->setName("William Shakespeare");

    displayData(str1);
    displayData(str2);
    displayData(str3);

    return 0;
}



void displayData(structure str) {

    int structNumber = str->getStructNumber();
    char *name = str->getName();

    fprintf(stdout, "Struct number = %d\n", structNumber);
    fprintf(stdout, "Name: %s\n", name);
}
```

The desired output of the above program is:

```
Struct number = 1
Name: Robin Hood
Struct number = 2
Name: Tiger Woods
Struct number = 3
Name: William Shakespeare
```

But the output is actually this:

```
Struct number = 3
Name: William Shakespeare
Struct number = 3
Name: William Shakespeare
Struct number = 3
Name: William Shakespeare
```

All the three structure variables carry the same value.
How am I supposed to get the desired output?
Please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your setter and getter functions are all operating on the global variable `obj`.  After your three calls to `newstructure`, `obj` is pointing at `str3`.  So all of your sets and gets will affect `str3` only.  The way to fix this is to make your setter and getter functions take a structure argument and operate on that argument instead of a global.

Comment: I clearly mentioned in the question. I dont want the users of my demo program to call the function `setName` by passing the `str1` as parameter. I want these functions to work in their own instances.

Comment: This isn't C++.  How do you expect to have a function to operate on three structures without passing in any arguments?

Comment: Some global. Or some macro. Or maybe someway i can do it.